# sqlite3: query file's UTF-8 encoding is not recognized automatically

Tags: character-encoding, sqlite, cygwin, default

I fed in the query for the database as follows:

```
sqlite3 database.db < query
```

and I got the message:

```
Error: near line 1: near "SELECT": syntax error
```

The query was encoded in UTF-8 and so was the database. I checked the database's encoding by:

```
$ sqlite databse.db
sqlite> PRAGMA encoding;
UTF-8
```

or convert I was still getting an error message,

```
Error: near line 1: near "PRAGMA": syntax error
```

but the file encoding query was returned with output. If I did not put the above line, but changed the fileformat to ANSI  instead, I did not get any error. Why can't sqlite3 detect the file format automatically? Is there an option to set the default encoding somewhere? I am using cygwin in Windows.

Comment: Which editor did you use to create the `query` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, your file contains a [byte-order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), which is not valid in SQL commands.

To prevent vim from writing the BOM, execute `:set nobomb` before saving.